# Getting all application extensions, and just applicaiton extensions for an object from MS Graph

Tags: json, odata, microsoft-graph-api

Assume I know the extension names I am looking for I could get a users extensions like so:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{OBJECT_ID}}?$select=extension_{{APP_ID_WITHOUT_GUIDS}}_SomeId,extension_{{APP_ID_WITHOUT_GUIDS}}_SomeValue
```

Or I could get the attributes from his member groups like so:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{OBJECT_ID}}/memberOf?$select=extension_{{APP_ID_WITHOUT_GUIDS}}_SomeId,extension_{{APP_ID_WITHOUT_GUIDS}}_SomeValue
```

However, what If I wanted to see all extension the token had paticular access to. `$select=extension_*` does not work I get the following:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Term 'extension_*' is not valid in a $select or $expand expression.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "3b4e14d6-3bbc-429b-8c45-b0fea629f4a6",
            "date": "2018-04-06T13:35:40"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there syntax to make this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't possible with Microsoft Graph (using v1 Directory Schema Extensions).  With Azure AD Graph API there is a function - [getAvailableExtensionProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#getAvailableExtensionProperties) - that should return all the available v1 directory schema extensions available in the tenant; this doesn't exist in Microsoft Graph.  If you use [Microsoft Graph schema extensions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_overview#schema-extensions), you can query /schemaExtensions to find all public schema extension definitions available for use in any tenant (although your app also needs to have been granted access to the underlying extended object - like `user`).

Hope this helps,